# Python: Merge Multiline Output into Singular List

Tags: python

I created a random generator to create a list with a set amount of strings. Each string is a mix of uppercase letters and digits. I then got the number of characters in each string. However, the output is coming out as it's own individual line. I need these output lines to result in a new list.

```
Current Output:

5

1

2
```

```
Desired Output: (5,1,2)
```

I am very new to python, please help. Below is my code so far:

```
import random
import string

chars = string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits
from random import randrange
A = [''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k=randrange(1,10))) for j in range(5)]

print(A)


def bubbleSort(A):
    for passnum in range(len(A)-1,0,-1):
        for i in range(passnum):
            if A[i]>A[i+1]:
                temp = A[i]
                A[i] = A[i+1]
                A[i+1] = temp

bubbleSort(A)
print(A)


#Output line 1: Original List
#Output line 2: Sorted List


for item in A:
  len(item)
  A2 = len(item)
  print(A2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `print(A2, end=', ')` in your final loop to print the items on the same line.

Comment: What a lifesaver. Thank you so much Michael! I started learning python this past week for my courses and am still trying to piece it all together. This was a simple fix that was a big help!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension instead of your last `for` loop:

```
print([len(item) for item in A])
```

Possible output of your posted code using this list comprehension in place of the loop:

```
['XXF8XQA2V', 'ACQ1A782', 'E', '6G1LC45', 'C']
['6G1LC45', 'ACQ1A782', 'C', 'E', 'XXF8XQA2V']
[7, 8, 1, 1, 9]
```